# Syntax else if in C

Tags: c, syntax

Sorry for troubling but I need a new pair of eyes.

```
case '2':
    printf("\n>>> Desligar equipamento <<<");
    do {
        printf("\nNumero? ");scanf("%d",&nr);
    }
    while (nr<1 || nr>99);

    if (retirar(nr, f_equipamento_uso, f_categoria)){
       registarHora(n, 0, equipamento, data); //moved from the else
       unblanker(nr, f_equipamento_uso, f_categoria);               
       //Imprimir Eq Disponiveis para verificar função abaixo
       printf("\nRemover dos Equipamentos Disponiveis? S/N");
       scanf("%c", &sn);
       getch();

       if (sn == 'S' || sn == 's') {
           printf("should remove from dsp"); 
           getch(); 
           //retirar(nr, f_equipamento_disp, f_categoria);
       }
       else {
         //This is the **bold else**
       }
    else {
       printf("Equipamento nao existe.");
       getch();    
    }                   
  } 
  break;
```

I have two if elses there.
Removing the **bold else** I can compile but doesn't work as pretended as it "elses" for the last if.
If I don't remove, I have syntax errors

Comment: You missed the closing brace `}` for outer `if`.

Comment: You just misplaced `}`

Comment: oh right, I had it on the end instead after the problematic else.

Comment: You are using an indentation style that encourages these sorts of errors. You would do well to switch to K&R style, where the } lines up with the keyword. Actually, in fact, you have mixed the styles, which is the worst possible thing to do.

Comment: Open a bracket/square-bracket/brace/string-literal-double-quotes and close it immediately, this way you wont have such trouble even if you don't use an IDE which can be setup to insert one automatically on pressing ENTER.

Answer (score 2):

You should insert `}` before

```
else {
       printf("Equipamento nao existe.");
       getch();    
    }
```

Then your code will look like this structure:

```
case constant-expression:

do
{
} while(expression);

if (expression)
{

    if (expression)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }

}
else
{
}

}

break;
```